# Javascript how to make object allow any key

Tags: javascript, object, initialization

In Angular (typescript), say I initiate this variable:

`myVar = {}`

Then I do a call that assigns this variable to a bigger object:

...
`this.myVar = response`

Then when I want to access something on this changed object, I keep getting errors that the keys don't exist. For example with this code `this.myVar.Name` would throw the error `Property "Name" does not exist on type '{}'`. How can I just bypass this error?

Something like `myVar: any` does the job, but I would still like to at least declare it as an object with something like `= {}`.

I'm looking for something like `{any}` or `any{}`

Comment: This should work - `myVar : any = {}`

Comment: Whats inside `response` ? There must be a better type ..

Comment: yes that does it man! Thank you. Post it as an official answer then I can mark it for you?

Comment: ... `Something like myVar: any does the job` how is the comment above different ?

Comment: @FreddyBonda - Glad to help you!

Comment: @JonasWilms I gave `myVar: any` as an example in my question. Obviously I am NOT looking for that then. I my case `myVar: any` does not indicate that it is an object. Where as `myVar: any = {}` does. Which is why this is the correct answer.

Comment: @freddy no it does not!! try `myVar = 5;` in the line below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue for [typescript types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html), and for that I would recommend adding a tag for typescript in your question. I think you can use the [`object` type](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2017/02/24/typescript-2-2-the-object-type), it does exactly what you want, that is accept any kind of key. So the code would be: `const yourVar: object = {};`

Comment: Yes thank you. `myVar = Object` is a good answer (just being more precise, maybe just add this in your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The following should work

```
let myVar: any = {};
```

Comment: Sorry your answer was the best at first but I think graciano's answer is better because `myVar = Object` is neater I think

Answer (score 0):

Just make it of type `any`.

`myVar: any;`

**Or better**, you can make an interface to represent the type of `myVar`, let's say that you have modal `Product` which has properties: `name, price, description etc...` and then `myVar: Product`

Answer (score 0):

You could type it as an object with variable keys:

```
 let myVar: { [key: string]: any } = {};
```

that way you could add more fine-grained typings to the object.